# How to make new text appear every 24 hours?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, setinterval

I have a list of 50-60 short passages from books, and I want a random one to display each day (using some combination of html/Javascript). How would I make it so that every 24 hours, a random passage is selected and displayed on the website?

I already looked into setInterval but it doesn't allow for 24 hours.

Comment: if user reload page then. javascript setInterval will not work.

Comment: yep exactly. I'm looking for a way to have the passage be the same for every user during each 24 hr period

Comment: Maybe u can add an api for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
function timer_passage(){
    var now = new Date()
    if (0==now.getHours() && 0==now.getMinutes()){
        console.log("reset")
        //do something you want

    }
    setTimeout(timer_passage, 60000)//exec myself after 60000 ms
}
```

this function will occur every 60 seconds,and print 'reset' in console when time to 00:00,

you should savethe time user open the web page,and compare the time with now,replace `if (0==now.getHours() && 0==now.getMinutes())`

Answer (score 0):

```
var today= new Date();
function setTextAndTime(){
    //Code To Set Text Here
    localStorage.setItem("Timer",today.getTime());
}


if(!localStorage.getItem("Timer"))
{
     localStorage.setItem("Timer",today.getTime());
}
else{
    var lastSavedTime=localStorage.getItem("Timer");
    var diffInTime = Math.abs(today.getTime()- lastSavedTime);
    var diffInHours = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 ));
    var idealIntervalTime=diffInHours>=24?0:diffInTime;
    setInterval(function(){
        setTextAndTime();
    },idealIntervalTime);
}
```

This will save time as session if that variable is greater than day will enter into if condition. And will check for session in 60 minutes.

Comment: `sessionStorage` will be cleared when user closes the browser, you should use `localStorage` for longer persistency.

Comment: Also, you don't actually need an interval. On page load you can set a `timeout` for the remaining time. So, if timer was set 4h 30min ago, you set a timeout to be executed in 19h 30min. (asuming that no user will stay on the page for more than 24h, which I think is pretty safe to assume).

Comment: @Cristy. Is This Perfect Now??

Comment: @RAVIPATEL, you was wrong in diffInTime. You could see my response :)

Comment: thanks @sanji_mika, but Thats was crispy was saying. user not gonna stay on page more than 24 hours. so if you are calling function for another 24 hours its same as setInterval. dont you think so? i am just checking remaining time and setting it for timeout.

Comment: @RAVIPATEL : 1) in_diff_milisecondes = localStorage.getItem('time_displayed') + 60000*24*60 - new Date().getTime() , it isn't today.getTime()- lastSavedTime ?
2) setTimeout the next 24h for displaying another passages, it's necessary because the user can leave the tab all the time. You can't say no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196410/discussion-between-sanji-mika-and-ravi-patel).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your demand, you can use LocalStorage (or Cookie) of browser. It works even if the user refresh the page, or close and re-open the page.

```
let funcDisplay = () => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('time_displayed') || new Date().getTime() - localStorage.getItem('time_displayed') >= 60000*24*60) // 60000 millisecondes * 24h * 60min
    {
            // Save LS time_displayed
            localStorage.setItem('time_displayed', new Date().getTime());

            // ...Your codes for displaying page... (Bonus : you could also use LocalStorage for saving array of displayed pages, if you want to avoid the same displayed pages)

            window.setTimeout(funcDisplay, 60000*24*60); //  after 24h, func display will re-execute
    } else {
            let in_diff_milisecondes = localStorage.getItem('time_displayed') + 60000*24*60 - new Date().getTime()
            window.setTimeout(funcDisplay, in_diff_milisecondes) // after xxx milisecondes, func display will execute
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.